How can I make my user redirect to /home base on their role?
I've created a dynamic sidebar that will only show a specific sidebar links depending on their session.role
I have here a 4 types of role

super_admin
division_office_admin
division_office
school_admin
teacher

What I did in my sidebar, is I created multiple set of function wherein it will only render a specific links

  if (role === 'super_admin') {
    return <UserAdminAccount />
  }

  if(role === 'division_office_admin'){
    return <DivisionOfficeAdminSideBar />
  }

  if(role === 'school_admin'){
    return <SchoolOfficeAdminSideBar />
  }

  if (role === 'division_office') {
    return <UserDivisionOfficeAccount id={sessionId}  />
  }

  // Otherwise, show regular user account based on data
  return data !== null ? <UserWithAccount id={sessionId} /> : <UserWithoutAccount />

And now I realized that if the user change the url, it will still show the page, what I want to do is if the user is not role he will be redirected to /home.
currently this is my
middleware.ts
export default auth((req) => {
  const { nextUrl, auth: user } = req
  const isLoggedIn = !!req.auth

  

  
  console.log("IS LOGGEDIN: ", isLoggedIn)

  const apiAuthPrefix = '/api/auth'
  const isApiRoute = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/api')



  const isApiAuthRoute = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(apiAuthPrefix)


  if (isApiRoute && !isApiAuthRoute) {
    return null;
  }


  const isAuthRoutes = authRoutes.includes(nextUrl.pathname)

  if (isApiAuthRoute) {
    return null;
  }

  if (nextUrl.pathname === '/' && isLoggedIn) {
    return Response.redirect(new URL(DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT, nextUrl));
  }
  

  if (isAuthRoutes) {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      return Response.redirect(new URL(DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT, nextUrl))
    }
    return null
  }

  

  if (!isLoggedIn ) {
    return Response.redirect(new URL('/login', nextUrl))
  }

  return null;
})

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!.*\\..*|_next).*)', '/', '/(api|trpc)(.*)'],

}

